# Polymer, hidding <paper-tabs> when binding in <core-pages>

Tags: javascript, polymer

How to control paper-tabs inside core-pages for hiding paper-tabs? Because i got clashing beetween them, like the image below:

[image: Tabs working in Schedule Guidance]

[image: See when the Coach section, the tabs got clashing]

As you can see, in Schedule Guidance tabs working , but when i changed to the Coach section. The tabs got clashing, how to hide the tabs after changing section?

Thanks in advance